# Onclick event is unbound from anchors with jqueryui selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, onclick, jquery-ui-selectable

Here is example:

https://jsfiddle.net/u90z12zd/

When I comment `$('ul').selectable();` onclick events on anchors work, with selectable events are unbound.